# How to store text elements from iFrame/table

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I want to get the text from a table in a site that has an iframe like this

```
<iframe id="frame1234" colidx="0" name="list" title="My list" 

   src="/    datalist/list_41300.jsp?servletpath=/abc/list_41300.jsp&amp;..  

   style="width: 100%; height: 434px;">
</iframe>
```

And when I inspect with developer tools in Chrome (F12) and select an element, the HTML code of the table appears and looks like this:

```
<html>

<body>
    <table class="list" summary="Mylist">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="tbl-hdr">
                    <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:sortCol('/source/list/abc_1234.jsp?jorp=1234&amp;ap=1','1234','no', event); return false;">
                        <img alt="Cat" border="0" title="Category">Items</b>
                    </a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbl-hdr-custom" id="1234_448575_120_24">
                <td align="right">
                    <a href="javascript:list_xy('00334','448575','Text 1');list_Open('1234','HG');">8575</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbl-hdr-body" id="1234_448543_121_24">
                <td align="right">
                    <a href="javascript:list_xy('00334','448543','Text 2');list_Open('1234','HG');">443</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tbl-hdr-custom" id="1234_448504_120_24">
                <td align="right">
                    <a href="javascript:list_xy('00334','448504','Text 3');list_Open('1234','HG');">98314</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to store the texts values (8575, 443, 98314) in a variable to apply a loop later in my code.

How can I get do this in javascript? I only have the Xpath and I see that in Javascript only is possible to getElementsByID().

I've tried with Xpath in Selenium IDE but is not found the element.

This Xpath I got it using Dev tools of Chrome.

```
//*[@id="1234_8575_120_24"]/td[2]/a
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I believe this is a CORS issue. You probably can't get the data through the iframe, but you can use PHP to print out the contents of the page to your page, and get them that way.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Selenium IDE extension in Google Chrome and try to mix the features of JavaScript to get the values to continue using on Selenium code. I don't know php.

Comment: Well, the PHP script is simple, but if you're not set up for it, it might be more than you're willing to do. I don't think there is a way to get the contents of a page from another website with JavaScript, as per CORS.

Comment: The issue is I cannot run php in the machine I'm working. I'm only using Selenium IDE that has the option to include JavaScript code.